# Accessing a sibling's value from a JSON Array in JSONserde?

Tags: hadoop, hive

**Given**
This is my JSON

```
...
    "actions": [
      {
        "action_type": "link_click",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "page_engagement",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "post_engagement",
        "value": "1"
      },
      .....
    ]
  }
...
```

I would like to map each `action_type`'s value into a specific column of my external Table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE raw_marketing_other.facebook_ad_cost_dtl_hrly (
   ...
   linkClick : int
   pageEngagement : int
...
)
```

For example, `linkClick` column will have the value of `1` derived from that json object.

**Question**
Is this possible in the mapping of serdeProperties? something like this.

```
create table ...
...
ROW FORMAT serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH serdeproperties(
    "mapping.linkClick" = "actions[action_type="link_click].value",
...
```

**Note**: where actions[action_type="link_click]" is meant to return the first occurence of json object with that condition?

If it is not possible through custom mappings, then is there any alternative solution for it?

References:
https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just load the data as is and then query it using the `get_json_object` UDF.

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE get_json_object(json_column, '$.actions.action_type') = 'link_click';
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, If the json is { actions : {"abc": "123"}}.

 Can I use the serdeProperties by doing "mapping.linkClick" = "actions.abc"?